# Tool for interactive numerical data visualization

Tags: user-data

What is the best Ubuntu application for interactively visualizing simple XY data? It needs to be able to do ONLY this:

1. Plot XY data (around 1M data points).
2. Use mouse to draw box around the plot to zoom-in. Then the selected area is zoomed (only the selected range is plotted).
3. The selected area of the plot can be conveniently saved into a text file.
4. Simple statistics is produced for the box selection: number of data points, min, max (and this can be written into a file).
   Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27812/cross-platform-create-reports-from-text-files/27838#27838

Comment: I don't know any tool that can do everything that you want. For example, I don't think that Libre Office Calc can manage 1 million data points. Gnuplot described in the answer by @Yaksha is a good candidate for the plotting, but you need another tool/method to manage the data statistically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gnuplot`.

It is a command line utility and works well.

---

**About the Software:(from http://www.gnuplot.info/)**

Gnuplot is a portable command-line driven graphing utility for Linux, OS/2, MS Windows, OSX, VMS, and many other platforms. The source code is copyrighted but freely distributed (i.e., you don't have to pay for it). It was originally created to allow scientists and students to visualize mathematical functions and data interactively, but has grown to support many non-interactive uses such as web scripting. It is also used as a plotting engine by third-party applications like Octave. Gnuplot has been supported and under active development since 1986.

---

**Installation**

```
sudo apt-get install gnuplot
```

You will have to look through the tutorials to accomplish the things you want. It is very well documented and couple of searches should get you what you want. Remember that you have to run it from the terminal ;) There's no icon to click on to launch it.

Comment: This is a good idea and I'm aware of GNUplot. I'm not sure, though, if it allows me to interactively zoom/scroll/crop the data using mouse?

Comment: Thanks! I can get the picture I want with GNUplot  (meaning that I know how to crop my data). How do I save the cropped dataset as it looks on the screen  (only the selected data points) as a tabular text file?

Comment: @T02134, I'm sorry. I used this tool once and don't have a working experience now. Please try to search it and find a proper solution for that. Thanks. If it doesn't serve the purpose, don't accept the answer and wait till you get the answer that you want. :)

Comment: Maybe someone knows a simpler solution than GNUplot. So here's a clearer summary of what I'mm looking for. I need a software tool that can let the user crop numerical data with mouse (draw a box around a section of a graph and extract it) and then send the selected coordinates into a new file. For example if you have a graph consisting of 3 points (1,2; 3,11; 7;21) and you draw a box around the center point then a new file is written that contains "3,11".